# How can I use case objects as a field in my case class and convert to Spark DataSet?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I'm learning spark-sql and trying to apply a filter in a DataSet created. I've defined a simple Employee case class, which has 3 fields, name, salary and dpt.

```scala
case class Employee( name: String, salary: Double, age: Int, dpt: Dept)
```

Last field dpt is defined like this:

```scala
 sealed trait Dept extends { val name: String }

  case object Accountability extends Dept { override val name = "AC"}
  case object Sales extends Dept { override val name = "S"}
  case object Finance extends Dept { override val name = "F"}
  case object Marketing extends Dept { override val name = "M"}
  case object Communication extends Dept { override val name = "C"}
  case object Reception extends Dept { override val name = "R"}
  case object HumanResource extends Dept { override val name = "HR"}
```

I've tried to use the kryo encoder to solve it, but it does not work.

```scala
 object DeptEncoders {
    implicit def deptEncoder : org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Dept] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Dept]
  }
```

Comment: perhaps you need an encoder for `Employee` too

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder

...
// conf is your org.apache.spark.SparkConf used to create your Spark Context
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Dept], classOf[Employee]))

...
implicit val encoder1:Encoder[Dept] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Dept]
implicit val encoder2:Encoder[Employee] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Employee]

...
val df = Seq(e1, e2).toDF()
```